# Calculating Conditional Value at Risk given any distribution

Tags: time-series, econometrics, finance, risk

Many CVaR methods calculations are based on VaR, which is based on the assumption on the normal distribution. How can I calculate CVaR given any distributions?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. The assumption of normality of errors is a parametric assumption. Methods not using this assumption - and not using instead an assumption of for example t-distributed errors - is therefore referred to as "non-parametric". So you can look around for non-parametric estimation of CVaR.

Comment: @JesperforPresident Thanks, I am new in CVaR, getting stuck in calculating CVaR given non-gaussian distributions.

Comment: In that case I would recommend you to have a look at Kevin Sheppards notes for financial econometrics page 474-75. Estimate GARCH model under assumption of normality. You get standardized residuals. Even if non-normal the estimates of the GARCH model are consistent so the standardized residuals can be used to get you an estimate of the distribution of the standardized residuals (perhaps using kernel method). The CVaR can be calculated using this empirical distribution.

Comment: Im not saying this is the best method but from a learning perspective I think this is a good place to begin (assuming you are familiar with GARCH models with normal standardized errors).

Comment: @JesperforPresident Thanks, I am not familiar with GARCH models, now the vanilla method I used to calculate CVaR is only sorting and returns and get the first `alpha*len(returns)` values and get the mean. But I think this is not a good way to do so.

Comment: My problem is training a model to predict the return of the target (select some stocks or something else) and calculate the CVaR. So, it is not that much time-related in the predicted returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an $n$-sized i.i.d.* sample of a random variable $X$, you can estimate $\alpha$-level conditional value at risk (a.k.a. expected shortfall or expected tail loss) parametrically or nonparametrically.

**Parametric CVaR.** Assume $X\sim D(\theta)$ where $D$ is some distribution with parameter(s) $\theta$. Let the corresponding PDF be $f_X(\cdot|\theta)$ and CDF $F_X(\cdot|\theta)$. Estimate $\theta$ from the data using e.g. maximum likelihood to obtain $\hat\theta$. Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^q x f_X(x|\hat\theta) \ dx$ where $q:=F_X^{-1}(\alpha|\hat\theta)$ is the $\alpha$-level quantile of the distribution $D$.

**Nonparametric CVaR.** Order the sample ascendingly. Take the mean of the first (i.e. lowest) $\alpha\times n$ values as an estimate of CVaR. (Some care is needed if $\alpha\times n$ is not a whole number.)

The parametric approach utilizes some assumptions about the distribution of $X$ and is **more efficient** when the assumptions hold but may fail otherwise. The nonparametric approach is **more robust** as it does not make assumptions about the distribution of $X$ (perhaps aside from those needed for the CVaR to be well defined).

*If your sample is not i.i.d. but some transformation of it is, utilize that. E.g. build a GARCH model ensuring the standardized residuals $\xi$ are i.i.d. For a given time index $t$, the distribution of $X_t$ will be a scaled version of the distribution of $\xi_t$. Then you can estimate a conditional CVaR for a specific time point $t$ or (if it is well defined) an unconditional CVaR for the data generating process in general. The parametric approach should still work, but the nonparametric one may fail depending on the nature of dependence between the observations.

Comment: Thanks, regarding the parametric methods, can I use many Dirac delta functions to estimate the distribution?

Comment: @GoingMyWay, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Hi, I mean using many (say, 10) Dirac functions to estimate a cost distribution given the data, I am using Deep Learning to do this. Thus, I can estimate the cost distribution and calculate the CVaR.

Comment: @GoingMyWay, this does not sound quite like the parametric approach I had in mind. But in principle you can estimate the distribution and then use the estimate to obtain an estimate of CVaR.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I used deep learning to estimate the Dirac Delta functions.

Comment: @GoingMyWay, glad to hear it worked well.